# Ruby on Rails - Omniauth facebook - expire session after logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authorization, omniauth, logout

I built authorization to Ruby on Rails application using omniauth and facebook. Unfortunately after logout from facebook, user is still logged in to Rails app.
How do I know that user was logged out from facebook?
I can't send authorization request every time when I need to trigger some action.

Is it possible that facebook will send some request after user is logged out?
Or maybe there is some cookie that I can read and I will know that user was logged out from facebook?

Comment: I don't know why this has been voted down ( I have voted up this question ). Also the accepted answer doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a logout in Facebook from your application [using the Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/). You can also use [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to detect whether the user is logged in to your application.

That being said, these have to be enabled through the Javascript SDK which is completely separate from the OAuth 2.0 API and the way that OmniAuth connects to Facebook.